# Rounded circle with text and color using CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cashapelayer

I want circle the corner based on percentage.
For Example if rating is 3 out of 10 .I want to circle the corner radius with one color and remaining with other color.

Below is my code:

```
 UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 5, 50, 50)];
[mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[viewAwesome addSubview:mainView];

mainView.layer.cornerRadius = mainView.frame.size.width / 2;

mainView.clipsToBounds = YES;
mainView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
mainView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

UILabel *lblRatingVal = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 5, 50, 50)];
lblRatingVal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[dictRelevance valueForKey:@"avg_rating"]];

lblRatingVal.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:59.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
lblRatingVal.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLight" size:6.0] ;
lblRatingVal.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[viewAwesome addSubview:lblRatingVal];

CAShapeLayer *circleLayerRating = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayerRating.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)].CGPath;
circleLayerRating.fillColor = nil;
circleLayerRating.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
circleLayerRating.strokeEnd = val;
circleLayerRating.lineWidth = 5;
[mainView.layer addSublayer:circleLayerRating];
```

[image: Expected Behaviour]

[image: Current Behavoiur]

I want to circle remaining with blue color.Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:
for drawing the circles. draw the blue circle first with 0-2π und the red on top.